# How can I install OpenCL in Linux Mint

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to install OpenCL in Linux Mint over an Intel Atom 1.8 32 bits CPU but in the Intel website there are only for 64 bits CPU.

Does anyone know how to install it using a 32 bits CPU?

Comment: OpenCL is an API for which there are many implementations. If you are having trouble installing a particular implementation, ask for help from the vendor of that implementation. If you are looking for an implementation that will support the hardware that you have, then please edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Intel's OpenCl runtime has high platform requirements (Core-family with SSE 4.1 for CPU computation or 3rd-gen Core processor for GPU).

Use AMD's OpenCL runtime. It requires just a processor supporting SSE2. http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/downloads/